# Replace content of a table with the results of a query in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table called #CSVTest_Data.
I wish to replace the content of that table with the result of the following query:

```
SELECT FirstTimeTaken, 
       LatestTimeTaken, 
       Market, 
       Outcome, 
       Odds, 
       NumberOfBets, 
       VolumeMatched, 
       InPlay
  FROM #CSVTest_Data
EXCEPT
SELECT OddsFirstTimeTaken, 
       OddsLastTimeTaken, 
       MarketName, 
       Outcome, 
       Odds, 
       NumberOfBets, 
       VolumeMatched, 
       InPlay
  FROM Data
```

I would appreciate if somebody can tell me how to achieve this. Thanks.

EDIT:

I worked out another way to do this from an idea that one of you guys gave me. It requires creating a new temp table and using that thereafter, but it works:

```
SELECT * INTO #CSVTest_Data_new FROM #CSVTest_Data WHERE 1 = 0;

INSERT INTO #CSVTest_Data_new
SELECT FirstTimeTaken, LatestTimeTaken, Market, Outcome, Odds, NumberOfBets, VolumeMatched, InPlay
FROM #CSVTest_Data  -- Coming data

EXCEPT --Minus

SELECT OddsFirstTimeTaken, OddsLastTimeTaken, MarketName, Outcome, Odds, NumberOfBets, VolumeMatched, InPlay
FROM Data --Existing Data
```

I think I will try Damien's idea though as that looks good and avoids an additional temp table. Why the down votes on my question? I know I'm a noob at this but that's why I need the helpful advice...

Comment: Check out `SELECT INTO`.

Comment: What do you mean by replace? Why not just deleting the things filtered out by the `except`?

Comment: The query identifies data that does not exist in the database all ready, so the idea is to make sure no duplicate data exists in #CSVTest_Data before I add the contents of that table to the main database table called Data. This is to avoid adding duplicate entries.

Comment: It seems like you are taking several extra steps that are unnecessary.  If you simply want to insert data to the main db table and avoid duplicate entries, `INSERT INTO...WHERE NOT EXISTS (some subquery)` would be much more direct and efficient.

Comment: But why do you need to replace the contents rather than, say, just executing a `DELETE` against the data already in there?

Comment: I don't think I can use the WHERE NOT EXISTS approach because I have to add another column of data to the table before inserting the data into the main database. This new column of data will be unique and therefore the rows will not be removed by the WHERE NOT EXISTS statement.

Comment: Damien, the query is performed on the table where I want the resulting data from the query to end up.

Comment: You could copy all your data in another temporary table, delete `#CSVTest_Data` and use `insert into #CSVTest_Data select * from #temp except select * from Data`. and then delete the temporary table. That would take more everything (time,effort, cpu) while the net effect is the same as just deleting a few rows as I and Damien do in our answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of seeking to replace a table, using a query based on the same table, just do a `DELETE`:

```
DELETE #CSVTest_Data
  FROM #CSVTest_Data d
WHERE EXISTS( SELECT * from Data d2 WHERE
    d.FirstTimeTaken = d2.OddsFirstTimeTaken AND
    d.LastTimeTaken = d2.OddsLastTimeTaken AND
    d.Market = d2.MarketName AND
    d.Outcome = d2.Outcome AND
    d.Odds = d2.Odds AND
    d.NumberOfBets = d2.NumberOfBets AND
    d.VolumeMatched = d2.VolumeMatched AND
    d.InPlay = d2.InPlay)
```

Comment: Thanks Damien. I had to edit the top line to add the table name in after DELETE to make this work. I will mark as correct answer once the edit is approved. My rep has taken a bashing on this question. Was up to 7 but now down to 3. Not sure why -2 gives me -4 though?

Comment: @SteveW - not sure, I'm afraid. You're correct about the required edit, so don't know why that was rejected. I've made it myself now.

Answer (score 0):

First, the table #CSVTest_Data must have the same number of columns as your SELECT query...
Then, you add at the top of  your query this:

```
INSERT INTO #CSVTest_Data
```

Answer (score 0):

```
delete #CSVTest_Data from #CSVTest_Data A
inner join Data B on
 A.FirstTimeTaken = B.OddsFirstTimeTaken and
 A.LatestTimeTaken = B.OddsFirstTimeTaken and
 A.Market = B.MarketName and
 A.Outcome = B.Outcome and
 A.Odds = B.Odds and
 A.NumberOfBets = B.NumberOfBets and
 A.VolumeMatched = B.VolumeMatched and
 A.InPlay = B.InPlay
```